update imports across all files after mass replacing a method header in subclasses
I have a method defined in a superclass, that is also defined in 32 subclasses
async fetchDepositAddress (code: string, params = {}): {

I updated this method to add a return type
async fetchDepositAddress (code: string, params = {}): Promise<DepositAddress> {

using vscodes search and replace tool

I must add the type DepositAddress as an import to all 32 subclass files. I would like to know if there is a quick method to do this to all 32 files at once. Right now I am going through all 32 files and using the quick fix update import form that appears when hovering over the text for the missing type


wait... do you actually need to do this? unless you need to manually use that type somewhere in whatever imports this function, I don't think you need to do this.
